# How to save value in excel from site using python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-requests, screen-scraping

below is my code I want to scrape the website and store value in the excel-

```
  **

import pandas as pd
        import requests
        from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
        from openpyxl import workbook
        
        Name = []
        Mob = []
        Add = []
        E_mail = []
        website = []
        
        headers = {
            'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.12; rv:55.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/55.0',
        }
        
        url = requests.get("www.example.com", headers=headers)
        
        soup = BeautifulSoup(url.content, 'html.parser')
        travel_name = soup.findAll(attrs={'class': 'list-group-item'})
        
        
        for name in travel_name:
            for a in name.findAll('a', attrs={"class": "text-warning"}):
                user = a.text
                Name.append(user)
            pList = name.findAll('p', attrs={"class": "mb-2 text-truncate"})
            for p in pList:
                #   print(p.text)
                if p.text.find("Contact:") != -1:
                    contact = str.replace(p.text, "Contact:", "")
                    Mob.append(contact)
                #    print(contact)
                if p.text.find("Location:") != -1:
                    location = str.replace(p.text, "Location:", "")
                    Add.append(location)
                #    print(location)
                if p.text.find("Email:") != -1:
                    email = str.replace(p.text, "Email:", "")
                    E_mail.append(email)
                #   print(email)
                if p.text.find("Website:") != -1:
                    web = str.replace(p.text, "Website:", "")
                    website.append(web)
```

**

**I want to store value in excel column-wise. I tried by df = pd.DataFrame() but I am failing
[Name, Mob, Add, E_mail, website]**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow below pattern hope you understand if not feel free to ask for more explanation:

```
    data=[]
    for name in travel_name:
        dict_={}   #i.e create a dict for each item i.e it will be representing a row in the excel
        name= [a.text for a in name.findAll('a', attrs={"class": "text-warning"})]
        contact=(code to extract the value like in name)
        email=(code to extract the value like in name)
        website=(code to extract the value like in name)
        data.append(dict) #i.e append each dictionary(later to be row in excel) into a list
    df=pd.DataFrame(data)
    df.to_csv('data',index=False)
```

Here name,contact,email,website will be the names of the columns and every iteration will create a row for these columns against your data.

Comment: contact=(code to extract the value like in name)  please explain this line that how to write?

Comment: yes like i've written for the name variable you need to write the tag in which that information is contained